# Why ExecutorService in this case returns correct answer 19 times? Where's the bug?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jsoup

This is the code. It scratch a forum post and display the results. It should return only 1 post but it returns 19 posts. Thread argument is a url of forum. First page and second page is a range to scrape.

```
@PostMapping("/search")
public String scrapPosts(@RequestParam(name = "thread", required = true) final String thread,
                         @RequestParam(name = "firstPage", required = true)final int firstPage,
                         @RequestParam(name = "secondPage", required = true)final int secondPage,
                                        Model model) throws IOException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = firstPage; i <secondPage; i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(thread + "page-" + finalI).get();
        Elements posts = doc.getElementsByClass("message-inner");
        posts.remove(posts.size() - 1);

        executorService.submit(()->{
                try {
                    for (int j = 0; j < posts.size(); j++) {
                        int finalJ = j;
                        postList.add(createNewPost(posts.get(finalI), thread, finalJ));
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    }
    executorService.shutdown();


    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(100000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Srednia cena to \n");
        model.addAttribute("postList", postList);


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not stop in alloted time");
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    return "search";

}
```

And the return is something like this:

[image]

Comment: The `Elements` class contains one `remove` method without parameters, your `remove(int)`method  where is defined ?